# Create a pointer sized union for 64 and 32 bit builds

Tags: c++, pointers, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, unions

I want to create a union like the following

```
union {
    long i;
    float f;
    void* ptr;
};
```

in which members i and f will always be the size of ptr (float & long for 32 bit / double & long long for 64 bit).

What is the best way to achieve this with minimal macro usage ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that union type-punning (writing one member and then reading another) is undefined-behaviour in ISO C++.  It *is* well-defined in ISO C99, and in GNU C++ as an extension.  (And some other C++ compilers, I think including MSVC.)  Also be careful with non-trivially-copyable types (with constructors/destructors) as union members.

There are of course uses for unions other than type-punning (e.g. hand-rolled polymorphism) where something like this could make sense.

---

**[`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) exists for this reason.**  (Or `intptr_t` or `ptrdiff_t` if for some reason you want a signed type).

**But for `float` vs. `double` you'll need the preprocessor**.  `UINTPTR_MAX` gives you a way to check pointer width with the preprocessor, unlike `sizeof(void*)`

Note that `uintptr_t` is usually the same width as a pointer, but the type name is defined as one that can *store* the value of a pointer.  This won't be the case for `floatptr_t` on 32-bit platforms.  (Fun fact: it will be on x86-64 for "canonical" 48-bit addresses<sup>1</sup>).  If this bothers you or you're worried it will distort how you think about `uintptr_t`, choose a different name; `floatptr_t` is short looks right even though it's "wrong".

```
#include <stdint.h>

// assumption: pointers are 32 or 64 bit, and float/double are IEEE binary32/binary64
#if UINTPTR_MAX > (1ULL<<32)    
  typedef double floatptr_t;
#else
  typedef float  floatptr_t;
#endif

static_assert(sizeof(floatptr_t) == sizeof(void*), "pointer width doesn't match float or double, or our UINTPTR_MAX logic is wrong");

union ptrwidth {
    uintptr_t  u;
    intptr_t   i;
    floatptr_t f;
    void    *ptr;
};
```

---

To test this, I compiled it [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguYsB6G6qaDBIgLYAHAnlQsQqt6gUCTGJBB2JMVVkuVRJVADYAFlUAI0JSBxZ0VQAzBlQmAht0UWSGCKZw1QBJbFqUhQqATyibVJYmxJjiBwJVMsdeioiCBALVQTwAL0xrOTxs1QBVKoA5ABUABTWAJQB9AFkLAA11WWxVCFpFgBlrjU17qIBKVVf1S1eCRrdMLAXikSlCK5fIEDzEXYEDR8SxyTAMQQzD6qL4/P45PJjDGg8GQ6GzLiyTCZeazSw6Ap4ZC7RyI4gECATaaobIQEEFXEEF4aAAivPGU0wLIgADcAugAFRPdLcLj%2BQLBVQAdzw6BGqmKmEELDAUl6LgKyAQ2LGsQBQPSsVE3WW6y2e0OJzywCpqjwoSVxG8wFlT3xsMsIhYXhYfgIxBVauNHAA7DCLG9VCJApyk/6E28U%2BHIW704n2WDs71snm3mLVRKw8R07G%2BbJ42SLIEBdNTjyW0LWeDIyM/fXG82mZhdng2x3hd3VSMQCA8H344PBbsFvyhxPwz2kCBsvPrIvprtwWO112N1Ot%2BD51JpQxpABWKSkHxSMyP1DSB68fjja0SdSE2hHwIaRXyeaUAGsQFkBIDEJKIYziO8YwADgATgSO84lkRhpASR8XDoMwzCfEC32kR9BBAYjgJfa9SDgWAYEQFBUHcPAyjICgIDQNiOJAYBkK4UhsnYoIQkoZJSNINommkQDSB4lxiQIAB5FgGEaKSsANNgyi0vBwmQTwRS1KTMAAD0wZARCCOTHwVW8pHk8M8AIpy6OYNgUH4fhGDwZJKMgaVUA8ENKKkABaHR0F5YAWBEHzeFoWhVAilTZFSlwogo39JFoG970fZ9X1Id8pHM5C4gizpgGQZBVGQ2CLlwQhYjkehVE0Vi3HYxV2peT8%2BF4IDSLA0hINkWgDDiZDJq4WauDMVDaDiWgzASHCpDw0gCLvYjirIqQKKo0gaNA%2BimIgJAeJ6jjyEoG7euIEAKhcGM1uE0TgkoiBJNo6SGmITT3IU1ilP0NSNK0zAdOAPT/vwQzjNM/6LKsmzJBBhy7NO4hXLsm9WHYRKBAYfzAogYLQu8cK0tkHKxAkOgCqkB8SP%2BsqLG2fZVFq%2BqY1ggwUogFhvEwF4IBaohuna9Iut4vrCS4AaSZG2ixoQTAmCwZ7Kc27bdv2qSyuO6jRogqCppmuaFqWla1o2xz6fZkqTdO0aLvgBjmMeu6uN94J%2BMEz6GDEn6/pKmSgZxxTlMh4GSu0on4cTgyrOR8KSrR6zbKx/R4Rxly3MAwmvM4L9eD8gL4CpzwaekOmGfEPKWbZg7SukCqqpquqGqayX8Gl/9Jrl7qnuH2QVYrng1dA6VNe1wO9YmmCzFmu9ULvNazFoWRBJjO99fwkA9pdw7Tfd9XPdga6x79h678DpRaFQ3ZEhDsOJKkqPgfk2OIfUgnR8SddKY1TkjPAJlwryWzhjHG2MQZFwJowIm3lp5VwprXMKDd0pNyZvlTabdjad0qtVJI%2BwADKAA1TQqgX6qEWrQGMqhthrAAOrNUHm1ACo8FYy0JAkKeQ0Z6XznqQBeOtKAswNifI2HNyJCBOmda8FtoIGDXrIDeW8iK733ofJ2RViFHVESozaXBj7bzPh3YxyixomRCCGEACQgA%3D%3D%3D) with x86 32-bit `gcc -m32` and `gcc` (x86-64), and MSVC 32 and 64-bit, and ARM 32-bit.

```
int size = sizeof(ptrwidth);

int size_i = sizeof(ptrwidth::i);
int size_f = sizeof(ptrwidth::f);
int size_ptr = sizeof(ptrwidth::ptr);
```

```
# gcc -m32 output
size_ptr:          .long   4
size_f:            .long   4
size_i:            .long   4
size:              .long   4
```

```
# gcc -m64 output
size_ptr:          .long   8
size_f:            .long   8
size_i:            .long   8
size:              .long   8
```

Thus confirming the union itself and each member have the expected size.

MSVC also works, compiling to `int size_f DD 08H` or `04H` and so on.

---

**Footnote 1**: on x86-64, canonical virtual addresses are 48-bit sign-extended to 64, so you *can* actually round trip a pointer value through `intptr_t`->`double` conversion and back without rounding error.  But not `uintptr_t`->`double` for high-half addresses that aren't at least 2-byte aligned.  (And `uint64_t` <-> `double` conversion is slow without AVX512F.)

On current hardware, non-canonical virtual addresses fault.

In 32-bit mode, linear addresses are limited to 32-bit.  PAE allows multiple 32-bit processes to each be using different 4GBs of physical memory, but seg:off -> 32-bit linear happens before page-table lookup.  It doesn't gain you a larger address space to use 48-bit `seg:off` addresses, so compilers don't do it.  32-bit pointers are the `off` part of a `seg:off` address, with the segment base fixed at zero, so they're the same as linear virtual addresses.  Same as in 64-bit mode with 64-bit offsets.

Comment: `uintptr_t` means a uint which can store the value of a pointer ... it's doubtful whether `floatptr_t` also meets that guarantee

Comment: `1UL << 32` is undefined behaviour if `unsigned long` is 32-bit (due to shifting by the width of the type or more). You could do `(1UL << 31) << 1`

Comment: @M.M: Good catch.  I fixed it with `1ULL`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64-bit and thus large enough to represent `2^32`.  Shifting twice avoids UB, but could result in `0`.  I was only testing with compilers running in x86-64 mode, even if they were targeting 32-bit mode, so apparently it wasn't internally shifting out all the bits to `0`, or masking the shift count to `1`.  Is it legal for the preprocessor to use a wider type than the target, because `#if UINTPTR_MAX > ((1UL<<31) << 1)` is still true with `gcc -m32` on Godbolt when `uint64_t dummy = ((1UL<<31) << 1);` is zero.

Comment: @M.M: I also added a section about type naming, good point.  But fun fact: `double` does meet that guarantee on x86-64.  Hmm, I could have *right* shifted `UINTPTR_MAX`.  But by at most 15 unless I cast it to unsigned long, to avoid UB on systems with 16-bit pointers?  I think `1ULL` is best.

Comment: In fact the C17 spec says that all arithmetic in `#if` directives is performed in `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` precision (even if you try to indicate otherwise with suffixes etc.), so your original code was actually correct I think

Comment: @M.M: oh good, glad I don't have to report a gcc bug about the `(1UL<<31) << 1` not being zero when evaluated in a `#if` :)  Thanks for checking on that.  Definitely want to file that in the "fun facts" category and use `1ULL` so the expression means the same thing when used in C proper.